# No such transport RPC with RabbitMQ in Celery & Django

Tags: python-3.x, celery, django-celery

Celery: 4.3.0 (rhubarb) and Python 3.7 version.

I try to start celery worker:

> celery -A proj_name worker -l info

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'No such transport: rpc'
```

My celery config in Django:

```
LATE_RETRY_QUEUE_NAME = 'late_retry'
FAIL_AUDIT_QUEUE_NAME = 'fail_audit'

# Celery configs
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'rpc://guest:guest@localhost:5672'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://guest:guest@localhost:5672'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    Queue(LATE_RETRY_QUEUE_NAME, routing_key=LATE_RETRY_QUEUE_NAME),
    Queue(FAIL_AUDIT_QUEUE_NAME, routing_key=FAIL_AUDIT_QUEUE_NAME)
}
```

Celery config is the standard one from the docs:

> **celery.py (/proj/proj_name/celery.py)**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj_name.settings')

app = Celery('proj_name')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

> **init**.py (/proj/proj_name/**init**.py) [Ignore the missing underscores, cannot format here]

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

What is going wrong?